# copy value from set of one type to set of another type in java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have two set object  `Set<Foo> fooSet` and  `Set<Bar> barSet`. `Foo` is the entity object and `Bar` is the DTO which i want to use for sending data to the UI. I want to copy all the properties from `fooSet` into `barSet`.

```
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Category_Id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long categoryId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="productCategory")
    private Set<ProductEntity> products;
}

public class BarDto {

   private Long categoryId;

   private Set<ProductDto> products;

}
```

I am trying to convert Entity into DTO object like:

```
public BarDto mapDomainToDto(Foo domain) {

        BarDto barDto= new BarDto();
        barDto.setCategoryId(domain.getCategoryId());
       //trying to do something like:
       barDto.setProducts(domain.getProducts());
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this in Java 8?

Comment: What's the relation between the Foo and Bar classes?

Comment: You can write a converter method for converstion and use like `fooSet.stream().map(e -> convertFooToBar()).collect(toSet())`, there are some library for mapping one model into another one like ModelMapper

Comment: This question is similar [How to map a DTO to an existing JPA entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46536060/how-to-map-a-dto-to-an-existing-jpa-entity)

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 itself doesn't provide such mapping feature and with pure Java all the left is manual calls of getters and setters as you already do:

```
BarDto barDto = new BarDto();
barDto.setCategoryId(domain.getCategoryId());
barDto.setProducts(domain.getProducts());
...
```

This is not bad itself as long as the number of such object mappings and parameters is low. For more complex object hierarchies I recommend [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/). ModelMapper is its alternative (IMHO, MapStruct is the way easier to configure and use, though it does the job the same).

```
@Mapper
public interface FooBarMapper {
 
    FooBarMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(FooBarMapper.class);

    BarDto fooToBarDto(Foo domain);
}
```

```
BarDto barDto = FooBarMapper.INSTANCE.fooToBarDto(domain);
```

Back to Java 8, I bet you refer to either Stream API, Optional or anything related to the functional paradigm. Again, there is not such feature in this or any newer verstion of Java. However, it might help you with mapping of collections of objects using the library above:

```
FooBarMapper mapper = FooBarMapper.INSTANCE;

List<Foo> fooList = ...
List<BarDto> barDtoList = fooList.stream()
                                 .map(mapper::fooToBarDto)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: IMHO I feel more flexible using `ModelMapper`, write some utility function and use in the entire application nothing else with any model

Comment: I have a positive experience with MapStruct. It's a matter of taste :) The OP can make a choice.

Answer (score 0):

Usualy we write model mapper. Or u can use some libraries like
http://modelmapper.org/getting-started/